# Page Rendering is taking time in initial load in Angular2

Tags: angular

**Current behavior**

Page Rendering is taking time in initial load in Angular2.page loading time taking 10 to 12 sec for rendering UI elements in every page load.

**Expected behavior**

Our requirement will be load the page with in 4 seconds

**What is the motivation / use case for changing the behavior?**

I am trying to open a another page from parent page. but UI rendering taking time in initial load. its taking 10 to 12 sec for rendering UI element for every refresh.

Script execution for creating UI element is taking time in build copy
we are using angular 2.0.1 and for build we are using gulp with systemjs build file

•   Angular version: 2.0.X

We are using latest version (Angular,Node ,Npm,Typescripts)

•   Also using lazy loading reduce start up time

Please share your ideas & suggestion for reducing loading time in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

First upgrade your angular version so it is compatible with the angular/cli 1.0.0
Second for production use `ng build --aot --prod`
It is that easy.